# CSS auto margin is not working for absolutely-positioned element

Tags: html, css, margin, menuitem

All the other divs worked well but when i got to this point it does not want to center it for some reason? I'm i missing something?

Take a look at the image link. The menu items is what i want to set the auto margins to. The margin for the ehigh works but not the sides.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/swtYb.jpg

```css
.Menuitems {
    position:absolute;
    margin: 120px auto;
    width:398px;
    height:26px;
    z-index:11;
 border-style: solid;
}

#mitem1 {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/cyKwZQj.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:75px;
    height:26px;
    z-index:6
}

#mitem1:hover {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/BMHScgr.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center
}

#mitem1:active {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/4Y4sMtq.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center
}

#mitem2 {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/GiAoMqC.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    top:0;
    left:77px;
    width:75px;
    height:26px;
    z-index:7
}

#mitem2:hover {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/XQKv9yC.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center
}

#mitem2:active {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/KQ07YMK.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center
}

#mitem3 {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/UPERy0F.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    top:0;
    left:154px;
    width:90px;
    height:26px;
    z-index:8
}

#mitem3:hover {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/EqkUtsr.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center
}

#mitem3:active {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/k54mb7V.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center
}

#mitem4 {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/QHExEjQ.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    top:0;
    left:246px;
    width:75px;
    height:26px;
    z-index:8
}

#mitem4:hover {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/BjKCQbw.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center
}

#mitem4:active {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/EVwDUoB.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center
}

#mitem5 {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/oKrhDAE.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    top:0;
    left:323px;
    width:75px;
    height:26px;
    z-index:8
}

#mitem5:hover {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/gnLuhed.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center
}

#mitem5:active {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/iqFh66v.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center
}

#menuline {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/4xOPK1I.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    left:75px;
    top:0;
    width:2px;
    height:26px
}

#menuline2 {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/4xOPK1I.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    left:152px;
    top:0;
    width:2px;
    height:26px
}

#menuline3 {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/4xOPK1I.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    left:244px;
    top:0;
    width:2px;
    height:26px
}

#menuline4 {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/4xOPK1I.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    left:321px;
    top:0;
    width:2px;
    height:26px
}
```

```html
<div class="topbox">
        <!-- Menu Items -->

        <div class="Menuitems">
            <a href="#">
            <div id="mitem1"></div></a> <a href="shows.html">
            <div id="mitem2"></div></a> <a href="codes.html">
            <div id="mitem3"></div></a> <a href="about.html">
            <div id="mitem4"></div></a> <a href="contact.html">
            <div id="mitem5"></div></a>

            <div id="menuline"></div>

            <div id="menuline2"></div>

            <div id="menuline3"></div>

            <div id="menuline4"></div>
        </div>
  <a href="#">
   <div class="divlogo"></div>
  </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Try [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: OP was asking why his approach to centre an absolutely positioned element didn't work; stating it's a "very poor method" is not helpful.  In any case - absolute positioning is a very useful and valid method for positioning an element - it can just be a bit of a tricky one and so the inexperienced will avoid it for no reason other than they don't understand it properly.

Answer (score 3):

The absolute positioning takes it out of the flow of the page and causes the centering from the auto margins not to work.

```
.topbox {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    z-index:11;
}
.Menuitems {
    margin: 120px auto;
    width:398px;
    height:26px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Will get the menu div positioned correctly. Get rid of all the absolute position on your menu items.

I made this Plunker it might be what you're looking for. http://plnkr.co/edit/wcRaJqvg0fsPT9HcBynf?p=preview

Comment: Removing it from document flow doesn't impact the margin: auto - they're different effects caused by the same statement.

Answer (score 1):

Block level elements are greedy. They use margins to take up the entire horizontal space they're in so that nothing is inline with them. If you set auto on both left and right then both sides want all the space, so they share - resulting in a centred object.

If you use position:absolute or fixed on a block level element it removes this greedy behaviour from the element.

Answer (score 0):

Change the position of `.Menuitems` to `relative` and that should fix the issue.

Comment: Changing it to relative puts it back in the flow of the page. The poster wants the element above the other page elements. You can tell by the absolute positioning and the z-index.

Comment: @JosephEvans i  changed only the .menu items to relative. That seems to work for the left and right margins but now the top is acting up. It moves the whole outer div (the topbox) down 120 rather than the actual menu items. –